# I don't think that some of my code is optimized

Tags: c++

I need some help with optimizing code, this isn't all of the code, just a part that repeats very similarly, so id like to optimize it

```
if (training && palisade) {
                cout << "what would you like to do?" << endl
                     << "1.Build a stone wall" << endl
                     << "2.Build training grounds(Built)" << endl
                     << "3.Train militia into men at arms with training grounds" << endl;
            }
            // If the training grounds dont exist but the palisade does
            else if (training == false && palisade) {
                cout << "what would you like to do?" << endl
                     << "1.Build a stone wall" << endl
                     << "2.Build training grounds(Allows more militia to be trained)" << endl
                     << "3.Train militia into men at arms without training grounds" << endl;
            }

            // If the training grounds exist but the palisade doesnt
            else if (training && palisade == false) {
                cout << "what would you like to do?" << endl
                     << "1.Build a palisade" << endl
                     << "2.Build training grounds(Built)" << endl
                     << "3.Train militia into men at arms with training grounds" << endl;
            }
            // If both do not exist
            else {
                cout << "what would you like to do?" << endl
                     << "1.Build a palisade" << endl
                     << "2.Build training grounds(Allows more militia to be trained)" << endl
                     << "3.Train militia into men at arms without training grounds" << endl;
```

training and palisade are booleans that I've declared earlier in the code. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "optimizing code"? What do you need to optimize: readability, execution speed, size, ... ?

Comment: there is a separate site for code reviews. I don't think you mean "optimize", more like simplify, deduplicate.

Comment: This question is not [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on Stack Overflow. Maybe you can post it in [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Do you want to remove code duplication?

Comment: As far as performance goes you probably are not going to gain anything meaningful. Your compiler likely already optimizes this. As far as readability you can definitely improve that.

Comment: @MarekR I want it to not repeat so much, it seems very clunky to me

Comment: Code review is the place to review working code.

Comment: @GaryNLOL when suggesting users post on CR it would be great if there was also a suggestion like "_Please read the relevant help center pages like '[What topics can I ask about here?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)' and  '[How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)_". In the current form the code above would likely be closed as off-topic because it [is missing context](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3649/my-question-was-closed-as-being-off-topic-what-are-my-options/3652#3652).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use variables to store the changing part.

Assuming that no tricly operator overload are defined, it can be done like this:

```
const char *trainingStr, *palinsadeStr;

if (training) {
    trainingStr = "Built";
} else {
    trainingStr = "Allows more militia to be trained";
}

if (palisade) {
    palinsadeStr = "stone wall";
} else {
    palinsadeStr = "palisade";
}

cout << "what would you like to do?" << endl
     << "1.Build a " << palinsadeStr << endl
     << "2.Build training grounds(" << trainingStr << ")" << endl
     << "3.Train militia into men at arms with training grounds" << endl;
```

Comment: `palinsadeStr = "stone wall";` that's some confusing variable naming there. (Also maybe `string_view` instead of `const char*`)

Comment: @GaryNLOL Thanks, fixed. But this code still cannot be compile because there are no `int main()`

Comment: @NathanOliver How did you know that? I cannot even say that that the checked things `training` and `palisade` are pointers.

Comment: @MikeCAT Nevermind.  Realized you're checking the bools, not he pointers.